# cant tab what ever i want in emacs indentation mode

Tags: emacs, indentation, html-mode

in javascript and html mode emacs cant make good indentation and all i want is make it better by hand but when use tab only use self indentation and not listen what i say :D

what can i do?

now

```
<html>
    <body>
      HTTP 404 ERROR !!
    </body>
</html>
```

what i want

```
<html>
    <body>
                                  HTTP 404 ERROR !!
    </body>
</html>
```

only example

Comment: Can you describe the problem more carefully and give an example? I just tried a toy html file in emacs and it indented it just fine. What isn't working for you?

Comment: i want use tab more than one for example i want create new code --- see new update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some modes offer "bouncing" indentation, where TAB will toggle the indentation level between a few alternatives. An example for javascript is `js2-mode`. I'm not aware of a more general solution.

However, note that if TAB is getting intercepted by the major mode's keymap, you can still insert a literal TAB character using `C-q TAB`. That is probably all you need.

Comment: what is delete tab? in c-q TAB ?

Comment: Depending on the mode, `backspace` should work to delete a tab.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want <kbd>TAB</kbd> to do indentation, you can bind it to just insert tabs.

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
   (lambda () (define-key html-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command)))
```